# How to create multiline graphs from a collection of rdta files

Tags: r

I have over 100 survey data files with the following filename structure in a common directory:

```
BD-1994.rdta
BD-1996.rdta
BD-1999.rdta
BD-2004.rdta
BF-1992.rdta
...
UG-1988.rdta
UG-1995.rdta
UG-2001.rdta
VN-1992.rdta
VN-1997.rdta
```

The leading two letters (eg "BD") represent a specific country (by its ISO code) and the four digits represent the year of a given survey.

I would like to process these data so I can create one multi-line, time-series graph of fertility rates per country where each line represents a year of the survey. For example, the first graph will be for "BD" (Bangladesh) and will display four time-series for years 1994, 1996, 1999, and 2004.

The structure of the individual files is as follows:

```
time     fertility
1        3.2
2        2.6
...      ...
7        2.4
```

My idea at the moment is to use rbind within a for loop and create one massive dataset with all the data in it.
Then I need to split the data neatly by country code, perhaps using a function like "subset" (but doesn't look like subset is the right tool for the job.

Any suggestions on how to perform this data management so I can then call the plot function in R on a dataframe that contains the survey data for all years within a given country?

Thank you

Comment: some hints toward a solution in the absence of taking the time to work out a complete solution: (1) use `lapply` on the list of files to get a list of data.frames; (2) use `do.call(rbind,DFlist)` to get one massive dataset (as you suggest); (3) use `melt` from the `reshape` package to get the massive data frame in a more convenient form; (4) use `ggplot` to separate out the plots appropriately. Some of this will take some fiddling.

Comment: OK - thanks for the sketch solution. I'll work on this now...

Comment: But - not sure why you suggest using lapply to get a list of the files. Won't list.files(pattern=".rdata") suffice?

Comment: I meant something like `datList <- lapply(as.list(list.files(pattern=".rdata"))); datFrame <- do.call(rbind,datList)`

Comment: the tedious/fiddly part is getting the appropriate columns set up to identify the year and country for each chunk, although that may not actually be as hard as I thought -- if you use `strsplit` and `gsub` on the list of files themselves (or just enter the vectors manually!) you can `rep()` them with an appropriate pattern to construct ID columns

Comment: @Ben. An easier solution would be to write a function that works on each file to return a data frame with `time`, `fertility`, `country` and `year` (which can be easily extracted using `substr`), and then use `plyr` to consolidate into a big one. See my solution

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach using `ggplot2` and `plyr`. The basic idea is to create two helper functions to (a) extract data from each `rdata` file into a data frame and (b) plot time series for each country. Once these functions are defined, it is relatively straightforward to use `plyr` functions to loop through the files to produce the required graphs. I would suggest that you run this code on your data, and report back with any errors that you get, since I am unable to test my code in the absence of any data.

require(plyr)

```
# function to extract data frame from each rdata file
get_data_frame = function(file_name){
    temp_env = new.env()
    load(file_name, temp_env)
    mydata  = get(ls(envir = temp_env), temp_env)
    country = substr(file_name, 1, 2)
    year    = substr(file_name, 4, 7)
    df = data.frame(mydata, country, year)
    return(df)
}

# function to save time series plot of fertility grouped by year
plot_country_data = function(country_df){

    require(ggplot2)
    p1 = ggplot(country_df, aes(x = time, y = fertility)) +
         geom_line(aes(group = year))
    ggsave(filename = paste(country_df, ".pdf", sep = ""))

}

# extract all rdata files in working directory
rdata_files = list.files(pattern = 'rdata')

# consolidate data into one big data frame
big_data   = ldply(rdata_files, get_data_frame)

# plot data for each country and save as pdf
d_ply(big_data, .(country), plot_country_data)
```